# Pettis integral on locally convex space and seminorms

Tags: integration, measure-theory, operator-algebras, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $E$ be a locally convex Hausdorff space, and $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space which we fix a positive Radon measure $\mu$. Assume that $f: X \to E$ is a function such that the [Pettis-integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral)
$$\int_X f d \mu$$
exists.

Let $p$ be a continuous seminorm on $E$. Is it true that the inequality
$$p\left(\int_X f d\mu\right)\le \int_X (p\circ f) d\mu$$
holds?

Context: This seems to be implicitly used in the proof of lemma 2.4 chapter VI "Left Hilbert Algebras" in Takesaki's second book "Theory of operator algebras".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost correct. Note that $p \circ f$ might not be measurable, which is why the right-hand side has to be replaced by the lower Lebesgue integral. The result then follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral#Properties) for the argument and the definition of the lower Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Thanks! Splendid answer! For my purposes, I can assume $f$ to be continuous, so no problem with measurability then, I think.

Comment: Glad this helped. Basically, I just copied the Wikipedia paragraph.. :-D

Comment: Somehow, I read over that part :D